SwiftUI Preview Failing within SPM package: Macro missing user approval
I've seen this issue before. In an iOS project I can go to the build logs and there I will find a button that allows me to trust the plugin.
In CI you can pass a flag to Xcode build -skipMacroValidation.
But I'm not in either of those environments. I am inside an SPM package. How do I approve this macro from here ?
swift-dependencies/Package.swift:PACKAGE-TARGET:DependenciesMacrosPlugin: error: [targetMissingUserApproval] Target 'DependenciesMacrosPlugin' must be enabled before it can be used.)

